# Django 1.8 Loggers settings are ignored

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm fighting with django logging since this morning and nothing... I've read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/) then searched Google and found [this](http://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangologging.html) and [this](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2015/01/27/Django-Logging-Configuration-logging_config-default-settings-logger/) and I ended with something like this:

```
""" --------------------------------------------------------------------
Django settings for uploader project.
-------------------------------------------------------------------- """
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Loggers
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
        },
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s.%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'development_log': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/development.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
        'production_log': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/production.log'),
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'uploader': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'development_log'],
        },
    },
}

import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

and this how I log my own data:

```
import logging
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .models import MFile
from .forms import MFileForm


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def upload(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    template = 'main/index.html'
    logger.debug('Executing upload() view')
    [...]
```

Files `development.log` and `production.log` are created but they're are empty and console shows standard logging output like:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 01, 2015 - 20:39:23
Django version 1.8.2, using settings 'uploader.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[01/Jun/2015 20:39:29]"GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2195
[01/Jun/2015 20:40:03]"POST /upload HTTP/1.0" 302 0
[01/Jun/2015 20:40:03]"GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2195
```

so am I misunderstanding something or django ignores those settings ?

Everything is run under virtualenv from python 3 which was created with

```
python3 -m venv --without-pip venv
source venv/bin/activate
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and the requirements.txt:

```
Django==1.8.2
flake8==2.4.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
mccabe==0.3
pep8==1.5.7
Pillow==2.8.1
pyflakes==0.8.1
wheel==0.24.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing logger for your app name itself under `loggers`. If your project name is `django_project` then change the following:

```
'loggers': {
        'uploader': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
        },
```

to:

```
'loggers': {
        'uploader': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
        },
        'django_project': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
        },
        [....]
```

I usually create an "applogger" as a `dict` instance for quick access before this section.

```
applogger = {
    'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'propagate': True,
}
```

And then finally modify the `loggers` section into something as follows:

```
'loggers': {
       'uploader': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'development_log', 'production_log'],
            },
        'django_project': applogger,
        'app_name_1': applogger,
        [....]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing `'level': 'DEBUG', 'propagate': True,` in the `loggers` part, cause after adding this logs started to show in console and files. Once again thanks.